# GitKraken Login TO VSO

Tags: gitkraken

I have registered an account with GitKraken and confirmed that I have rights to a repo on VSO.  When I attempt to login, my uid and pwd and cleared from the text box and I can't login

[image]

[image]

Any guesses where the point of failure is?  When I use Visual Studio, I can log into that TFS repo no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use your VSO login directly in Git Kraken.

There are two ways you can approach this:
- Use a personal access token. In VSO, click on your profile icon -> Security - Personal access tokens. Create a new access token and use that as a password. Personal access tokens have an expiry date, so you will have to create a new one after some time.

- use ssh. That is what I am using, as I think it is more convenient, but a bit more steps to set up. Here is a tutorial on how to set it up with VSO: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/vsts/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=vsts